# Assigning derived object reference to variable of base class won't work

Tags: java

Here's an example.

```
Class A {
    Method A();
    Method B();
    Method C();
}
// A and B are not interfaces 

Class B extends A {
    Method C(int);
}

Class Harness {
    A ob = new B ();
    ob.C(3);
}
```

IDE complains that `ob.C(3)` cannot be made to method `C` in `A` since `C` expects no parameter. But as I understand I am calling method `C` in `B`.

As I understand the variable type determine the set of method to be called with the objects whose reference it's assigned to, but the actual object determine the exact method that will be called. So why is it not working?

Comment: Setting aside that your code is not compilable ... There is a method `C` in your class `B`. So calling `new B().C()` is completely fine. There can't be any compiler error for this. I therefore vote to close as unclear. Please edit your question and provide a compilable example that exactly explains the problem you have.

Comment: I have edited the question.  Please have a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: @RajeevSingh *"C can be called like this ob.C (3);,code looks fine"* This is wrong and `ob.C (3);` won't work.

Comment: @RajeevSingh No it doesn't. As long `ob` has the declared type `A` and `A` doesn't has the method `C(int)` it won't work.

Comment: End th fighting.  It doesn't work and that's why I asked why it doesn't.

Comment: @Tom I will take a look at it..it think i got confused..well thanks for mentioning.

Comment: We don't fight ;). Also you got two good answers (the upvoted ones) which explains why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Tom. Yeah. I appreciate

Answer (score 3):

You've assigned an object of type `B` to a variable of type `A`. The class `A` does not have a method `C` on it and the compiler is complaining because it has to link to methods based on the variable's *declared* type - i.e. `A`. Unless the type `A` has some kind of declaration of the method `C` there's no way the compiler can know that it's safe to call that method on a reference to an `A` type.

Comment: Isn't it tha the object itself will determine the exact method that will be called?

Comment: Only to some extent. The compiler does not allow for *any* method to be called - only methods which are defined on the variable's type. A subclass instance *might* override a method, and that would be the method which is called at runtime, but the method signature must be declared for the type associated with the variable.

Answer (score 2):

As you have mentioned in your question itself that, the type of the variable determines what are all the methods that can be called using it. In your example, `class A` doesn't have a method with signature `C(int)`. It only has a method with signature `C()`. So, the method `C(int)` in B is not even an overridden method. It is an overloaded method.

Runtime Polymorphism only applies to overridden methods.

You will have to make `class A` to have `C(int)` method to compile this code successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `new B` to be an instance of `A` and a does not have method `C` to get it work you wold have to again at least cast your `ob` it B. So assumig this is a pseudocode, this would work:

```
 A ob=new B ();
  ((B)ob).C ();
```

Comment: I am calling method C(int a) in class B not the one in Class A.

Comment: In your case, despite fact that `ob` is indeed the instance of `B` class, you are declaring it as instance of `A` so you will have access only to methods and fields delcared in `A` type. To get to the `B` members, you have to explicity cast ("redeclare") your `ob` into `B` class. It is simple as that.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you.

Comment: Now you need to pass an `int` into the method call, so it is worth to cast to `B` :D.